# How can I change the colour of the notification logo in the status bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, colors, android-manifest

I want the colour of the notification logo to be the native colour in the notification, but the same as all the rest (grey) in the status bar.

How can I do this please. This is what I have so far.

**ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/logo_native" />
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

**COLORS.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorAccent">#BFBFBF</color>
</resources>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can used setColor for change notification color like below and logo must be transprent Background to reflect color

```
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int notification_ID = 0;
        String channel_ID = "xxx444";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_ID)
                    .setColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentText("Review Reminder")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setChannelId(channel_ID)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            mNotificationManager.notify(notification_ID, mBuilder.build());

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_ID, "Review Reminder", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channel_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_ID)
                    .setColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentText("Review Reminder")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            mNotificationManager.notify(notification_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: Where would this go please @mehul chauchan

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is supporting 2 kind of messages, “data” and “notification”. You have to use the “data” format and build styled yourself notifications include the color of icons. Look at details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Hi Im not too sure what you mean sorry

Comment: It means, if you’d like use own color and that should works on all phones/os-version - you have to use the “data” format for Firebase messages. Look at my link details above.

Comment: Hi @Maxim Firsoff, I have already done that. It works, but it appears the colour in the status bar aswell.